# BigQuery: Querying repeated fields

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to use the following query to get the rows for which the event names are equal to: EventGamePlayed, EventGetUserBasicInfos or EventGetUserCompleteInfos

```
select *
from [com_test_testapp_ANDROID.app_events_20170426]
where event_dim.name in ("EventGamePlayed", "EventGetUserBasicInfos", "EventGetUserCompleteInfos");
```

I'm getting the following error: Cannot query the cross product of repeated fields event_dim.name and user_dim.user_properties.value.index.

Is it possible to make it work by not having a flattened result ?
Also, I'm not sure why the error is talking about the "user_dim.user_properties.value.index" field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is due to the `SELECT *`, which includes all columns. Rather than using legacy SQL, try this using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/), which doesn't have this problem with repeated field cross products:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM com_test_testapp_ANDROID.app_events_20170426
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(event_dim) AS event_dim
WHERE event_dim.name IN ("EventGamePlayed", "EventGetUserBasicInfos", "EventGetUserCompleteInfos");
```

You can read more about working with repeated fields/arrays in the [Working with Arrays topic](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays). If you are used to using legacy SQL, you can read about differences between legacy and standard SQL in BigQuery in the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql).

Comment: This returns a row for every element of the array. Think of it like a `for` loop over the array for each row, e.g. `CROSS JOIN UNNEST(event_dim) AS x` is like `for (x : event_dim) { ... }`.